# How can I improve the following AWK script?

Tags: awk

The script takes 3 input arguments which are:

- a file which contains some strings to be replaced and the replacements
- an input text file which may contain the strings
- the name of an output file where I store the converted records

The script I used is:

```
BEGIN   {
    while (getline < ARGV[1]) { 
        subs[$1]=$2;    #store the replacements in an array
        original[$1]=$1; #store the originals in a different array
    }               
}
{
if (FILENAME == ARGV[2]) { # I need this because otherwise the script runs on every input file
    for (i in original) {
        if ($0 ~ i) { # replace string
            gsub(i, subs[i]); # maybe sub is better here
        }
    }
    print $0; # debug purposes
    print $0 >> ARGV[3] # append on the output file
}
}
```

It works, but since I'm still learning AWK I don't know whether there are easier ways to do it. I still don't understand if I can select only an input file among different arguments, and how.

An example of the first file is

```
awk Awk
unix UNIX
o O
```

The input file:

```
awkscriptAsInput
contains unix e UNIX
and other stuff
```

The expected result:

```
AwkscriptAsInput
cOntains UNIX e UNIX
and Other stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your requirement right, your awk script could be done in this way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]=$2;next}{for(x in s)gsub(x,s[x])}7' file1 file2 > file3
```

#### short explanation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]=$2;next} // save file1 into an array, like s[awk]="Awk"
     {for(x in s)gsub(x,s[x])} //for each pattern/replacement pair, do gsub on the line
     7' file1 file2 > file3 // print the line. 7 here is non-zero number, it does default action: print
```

if you want to always append data to your file, use `>>` instead of `>`

Note that if your replacement file (file1) contained the recursive replacement patterns,  the result could be different. E.g.:

```
 awk Awk
 ....
 A a
```

Comment: Could you please expand a bit more your answer? Right now I have no idea what this does :/

Comment: @ThCP first of all, could you tell if the my one-liner does the job correctly? and are the codes in your question written by you?

Comment: The oneliner does not work, the output is equal to the input. I wrote the code in the question, yes.

Comment: @ThCP add some example and expected output in question, so that I can see why it didn't give you the desired output.

Comment: I added the examples as you asked

Comment: @ThCP oh, I see, I misunderstood your requirement, I would post the corrected version soon

Comment: @ThCP corrected the answer and added short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Kent's solution, the following will keep the order of replacements to preserve side-effects which might be intentional.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f[++c]=$1;r[c]=$2;next}{for(i=1;i<=c;i++)gsub(f[i],r[i])}1' dict input
```

Explanation: collect the dictionary find/replace words in the arrays f and r respectively (using line number as the array index) from the first file (dict). In the second file (input) find/replace dict words in their given order. `1` enforces printing the result, here instead you can also use print

```
awk ...gsub(f[i],r[i]);print}' dict input
```